# BigQuery streaming from dataflow failing silently

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have had a successful pipeline running streaming data from `pub/sub` into `bigquery` using cloud `dataflow` which is running on a compute instance, rather than an actual `dataflow` runner.

Today I have updated the BQ table schema, and no new inserts seem to occur. I can view logs on the machine and all is fine - `dataflow` is not reporting any errors.

Is there any way to access streaming logs from `bigquery` to check for errors.

EDIT: To summarise my question is whether I am able to get some more verbose logging either from the apache beam SDK or from bigquery to see where this data is ending up.

I have had a look in `stackdriver`, but this does not seem to create entries for streaming logs.

Comment: What version of Beam are you using? The bq sink has an insert_retry_strategy parameter that allows you to set how to behave when there are errors inserting data to BQ: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L1067-L1068

Comment: I am using `2.15.0` - however this would not give me any indication of an error?

Comment: This is a (serious) design flaw. The pipeline has a deadletter queue - it returns a PCollection with the failed records, but if that PCollection is not used, the records won't be consumed. I have created https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-8803 to track this

Comment: Thanks @Pablo is it possible to read that PCollection somehow?

Comment: Yes! the transform returns a dictionary, where the only element is a PCollection with the failed insertions: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L1242

Comment: I can add that as an answer if it helps?

Comment: You can check this - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-4650. In the Java SDK there is `InsertRetryPolicy` which passes a handle back for records that have failed. The python SDK doesn't support it at the moment and the JIRA i mentioned is tracking that.

Comment: @Pablo I think that should be an answer!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In versions 2.15 and 2.16, Beam now produces a deadletter PCollection containing all of the rows that failed to be inserted.

This setting is configurable, with the `insert_retry_policy` parameter. The default for 2.15 and 2.16 is `RETRY_ON_TRANSIENT_ERRORS`. Starting on 2.17, the default will be `RETRY_ALWAYS`.

You would do the following:

```
result = my_collection | WriteToBigQuery(...,
                                         method='STREAMING_INSERTS', ...)

failed_rows = result['FailedRows']  # You can consume this PCollection.
```

You may also choose to always retry:

```
result = my_collection | WriteToBigQuery(...,
                                         insert_retry_policy='RETRY_ALWAYS',
                                         method='STREAMING_INSERTS', ...)
```

This will cause that nothing is output to `failed_rows`, and your pipeline may rnu forever.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to get your data stream logs from BigQuery, please take a look on this docs[1][2]. Be aware that modifying the schema of a table can take several minutes to propagate changes, and if it has recently received streaming inserts may respond with schema mismatch errors.

In this case,when BigQuery encounters a schema mismatch on individual rows in the request, none of the rows are inserted and an insertErrors entry is returned for each row including detailed information about the schema mismatch.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#streaming
[2]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/#mapping_audit_entries_to_log_streams